# Clear Django Cache

Tags: django, django-cache

I am using django 3.0. How do I clear cache in my django project.

I have tried the below two methods given out as answers to questions in the this forum but they are not working out:
python manage.py clean_pyc
python manage.py clear-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this **pycache** folder within your django app. [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.clear()
```